# Firefox AddOn: Font references not loading

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have a Chrome Extension I am in the midst of porting over to a Firefox AddOn. The extension is built with React and Webpack. The font references in the SCSS files (and generated CSS files) are using this to reference the URLs:

`src: url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/static/fonts/Muli-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");`

And this works great for Chrome. However, in the ported version to Firefox, the fonts don't load. How do I reference the fonts location in Firefox?

Comment: Won't work in FF. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources): the UUID is random so **I guess** you'll have to read the file with XHR/fetch, replace the URLs using browser.runtime.getURL, then use browser.tabs.insertCSS.

Comment: Actually just removing the entire `chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__` and using the path without the prefix works fine.

Comment: The full URL is needed when you inject CSS into the web page via content_scripts key or using browser.tabs.insertCSS. It's not needed in extension's own pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems FF AddOns will allow you to reference fonts from your CSS with just the direct path. Removing the `chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__` from the URL works fine.

Comment: That didn't work for me (FF 113, MacOS). Instead, I replaced 'chrome-extension' with 'moz-extension'. So: src: url('moz-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/font/myFont.woff2') format('woff2');